# Controlling result by another query

Tags: sql

I have this data in one table (Table1)

```
ID  Period  FileName    CreateDate          Creator
102 2014-03 2014-03.XML 22/01/2014 17:04:59 Me
103 2014-03 2014-03.txt 22/01/2014 17:04:59 Me
98  2014-02 2014-02.XML 22/01/2014 14:05:44 Me
99  2014-02 2014-02.txt 22/01/2014 14:15:36 Me
55  2013-02 2013-02.XML 22/01/2014 14:05:44 Me
56  2013-03 2013-03.XML 22/01/2014 14:15:36 Me
```

I also have another table which I want to lookup when I query the table above (Table2)

```
ID  Country Identifier          
1   ES  1           
2   ES  3           
3   ES  4    -- this identifier is unique in 2014       
4   ES  6
```

Now what I need is to display the rows depending on the values returned by the query:

```
Select top 1 1 from Table2 where Identifier=4
```

If the above query will return a value (1), I want to display only the txt files with a period of 2014 and all the file in 2013 and below, and if it did not have a value then display everything.

I have tried some queries but I cannot achieve what I want to display in the results.

EDIT:

If Identifier=4 is not existing then I expect this result

```
ID  Period  FileName    CreateDate  Creator
102 2014-03 2014-03.XML 22/01/2014 17:04:59 Me
98  2014-02 2014-02.XML 22/01/2014 14:05:44 Me
55  2013-02 2013-02.XML 22/01/2014 14:05:44 Me
56  2013-03 2013-03.XML 22/01/2014 14:15:36 Me
```

else

```
ID  Period  FileName    CreateDate  Creator
103 2014-03 2014-03.txt 22/01/2014 17:04:59 Me
99  2014-02 2014-02.txt 22/01/2014 14:15:36 Me
55  2013-02 2013-02.XML 22/01/2014 14:05:44 Me
56  2013-03 2013-03.XML 22/01/2014 14:15:36 Me
```

Comment: Can you add what you expect as output? As well as the query that didn't work?

Comment: I'm missing the link between the two tables. How can you see identifier 4 is unique in 2014? What does table 1 have to do with anything?

Comment: Because in 2014 .txt files are intorduced and will be the default file and before that its XML, change in procedure

Comment: I'm leaning towards what @CompuChip is referencing - find a better way to link the tables/data.